# Getting to the inner object

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I have a loop that runs multiple times and is prone to exceptions (it is web based). However, I don't want to throw anything directly from the method as I want it to move on the next iteration in case of an error. So what I did was I added a reference parameter that the caller passes, and all exceptions are put there.

I want to return to the user the Exception as well as the fault URL, so I created the following object:

```
class KeywordException
{
    Exception ex;
    string faultURL;
}
```

It is returned to the user as `ref List<KeywordException> exceptions`

Ok it's all good so far, and I catch exceptions like so:

```
catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
{
    exceptions.Add(new KeywordException(ane, URL));
    continue;
}
```

It works and the exception is returned to the user, but how can I from the calling code know what the exception actually was? All I get is `Exception` when it is actually an `ArgumentNullException` in this case.

Comment: Why doesn't your KeyWordException inherit from Exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your KeywordException class is storing the exception as an Exception (which makes sense and is probably correct).

Why do you want to know the exact type of exception?  Is it to display a message to the user?  In this case you can use reflection to get the concrete type of the ex variable:

```
string exceptionType = keywordException.ex.GetType().Name;
```

Comment: Can I use this to get the full exception? Something like `var exception = keywordException.ex.GetType();`?

Comment: No that gives you the Type object.   You already have the full exception in the ex vairable.  It is just cast as an Exception and needs casting back to the actual type.    See my comment in the answer above..   You need to create your own class that you return back to the user.  This class should describe the outcome rather than passing Exceptions and expecting the user to know what to do with them.

Comment: You are right, I will create my own exception. It is far easier and will work better for the user.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't even have to be an Exception, but simply a "Result" class, that gets passed back even when the request is successful. When an error occurs, you can flag this in the result and include the specific type of Exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the [`InnerException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception.aspx) property - it exists on every exception.

This information would also be on the stack trace of the exception.

One of the constructors of `Exception` takes an `Exception` - if you use this, the `InnerException` will be set to the passed in exception.

Comment: so Exception ex = new SomeOtherException causes the inner exception of ex to be SomeOtherException?

Comment: @TheGateKeeper - Only if you pass in the actual exception to the constructor.

Comment: @TheGateKeeper: Does your `KeywordException` class *actually* derive from `Exception`? If not, I suspect that `InnerException` is a red herring here. If you do, please update your question with a more accurate example - and say what you're trying to do with the exceptions, too.

Comment: No it doesn't inherit, it's just a container object that hols 2 different objects.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the *compile-time* type of `KeywordException.ex` is just `Exception`, when you log it you'll see the real object. You *could* test for specific types using:

```
if (keywordException.ex is ArgumentNullException)
```

but I doubt that you want to do that. You should be fine to just log the exception unconditionally - or display it to the user in whatever form you want.

EDIT: You can call `GetType()` on the exception to get its type too, of course:

```
Type exceptionType = keywordException.ex.GetType();
```

... but it's still not clear why you want to treat some exceptions differently to others.

EDIT: If you need to use the type-specific information in the exception, you should use something like:

```
WebException webException = keywordException.ex as WebException;
if (webException != null)
{
    // Use webException here
}
```

Comment: I think I will have to use the `is` for this, I see no other way to know what the Exception actually was from the calling code.

Comment: @TheGateKeeper: Why do you *need* to know? What are you trying to *do* with the exception?

Comment: I need to know because some exceptions have specific details I need to use. I would be fine using the generic `Exception.Message` in most cases but in the case of `WebException` I need to know the value of `WebException.Status` to show the real error to the user.

Comment: @TheGateKeeper: Okay, will update the answer again. (In future, please include information like this in the question.)

Comment: This sounds to me like you need to create your own return types to describe the outcome of the operation.  Passing Exceptions back to the user isn't the best way to go.  Especially if the Exceptions are actually expected and specific ones get dealt with differently.